# How to configure Rets server in local wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, rets

I am trying to connect to MLS Rets server in my local wordpress but can't connect.
I also don't know how to use Rets Server and get data from there? Also need some real estate sample data for testing purpose.
Does Anybody have any idea. How can I do that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not familiar with that wordpress plugin but you would get your login information and other details on connecting from the MLS that you are subscribed to. They could potentially have restricted access times or have IP restricted access among other general inconveniences causing you to not be able to connect.

Once connected, if you were looking for sample data then you would set your batch to a few hundred properties or something just to start. Or its possible that the MLS offers a sample set of data  or a test server to use in developing your application.

**to answer your comment**

You have to be a member of one. Multiple Listing Services are organizations that realtors belong to in order to share their listing data through broker reciprocity. There are several hundred MLSes in the US alone and although many of them use the RETS standard (which really shouldnt be considered a 'standard' in the first place) there is absolutely nothing standardized about them beyond a few similarities here and there... im not sure about other countries... There is also a way to become an IDX vendor for MLSes.. This usually involves setup and monthly fees and strict approval processes.. In that case you would be selling your IDX service to a member of the MLS in question. If your not a realtor and just want to display listing data im pretty sure your going to have a hard time getting approved to do so.

Comment: Ok. but where I can create or Register for MLS??

Answer (score 1):

You need to Connect RETS Service Provide they will give Credential once you register as agent under that agency and Provide Limited Access for RETS Data Feed once Again you can check your credential working or not using http://retsmd.com or if find any issue i having Script PHRETS and RETS IQ we will discuss if you facing any other issue.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Andrew's answer - to get RETS credentials, you'll not only need to have an agent sign off for you, but you'll also need to get their broker in charge to approve it.  Most agents choose to use a third party service that is already setup as a vendor since it can be a months or year long process for a new vendor to get setup and approved.  Especially if that vendor doesn't already have standing relationships with other MLSs.

Some MLSs charge vendor fees that can range from $0 to as high as $5000 / month for access.